# Explain this shift-reduce conflict

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

Below is a very simplified XML grammar for Bison:

```
head    : NODE_START NAME atts
        | NODE_START NAME
        ;
element : head NODE_CLOSE NODE_END
        | head NODE_END anys NODE_START NODE_CLOSE NAME NODE_END
        | head NODE_END NODE_START NODE_CLOSE NAME NODE_END
        ;
text    : TEXT
        ;
comment : NODE_START COMMENT_START COMMENT_END NODE_END
        ;
cdata   : NODE_START CDATA_START CDATA_END NODE_END
        ;
attr    : NAME EQUALS value
        ;
value   : QUOTED
        | APOSED
        ;
atts    : attr atts
        | attr
elt     : element
        | comment
        | cdata
any     : elt
        | text
        ;
elts    : elt elts
        | elt
        ;
anys    : text elts anys
        | elts
        | text
        ;
s       : any
        | PROLOG any
        ;
```

The alleged conflict is the rule `anys -> text`.

When I look at the corresponding output:

```
State 35

   21 anys: text elts . anys

    NODE_START  shift, and go to state 1
    TEXT        shift, and go to state 2

    head     go to state 4
    element  go to state 5
    text     go to state 25
    comment  go to state 7
    cdata    go to state 8
    elt      go to state 26
    elts     go to state 27
    anys     go to state 42
```

How do I understand what is at conflict here?

Comment: So you want an explanation on how to debug your `yacc` output?

Comment: @G_V that may be interesting, but I'm more interested in understanding what conflict is it talking about, a conflict between what and what?

Comment: @G_V is it possible that what it means is that the conflict is between which action to take: to shift or to reduce? In this case it doesn't even report the location correctly...

Comment: @G_V actually, nevermind, I figured it out.

Comment: Great! Could you post the solution as an answer to your own question and accept it please?

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Interpreting the dump file

If you look at the beginning of the .output file, you will see the following:

```
Rules useless in parser due to conflicts

   23 anys: text


State 26 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
State 27 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce
```

The first warning tells you that the production `anys: text` was eliminated altogether because the resolution of parsing conflicts (elsewhere in the grammar) made it impossible for the rule to ever be used. (Thus, it is "useless".) The next two lines tell you where to find the conflicts: in states 26 and 27.

So the rule you quote is *not* the "alleged conflict" and the state you quote has nothing to do with conflicts (indeed, I have no idea why you focused on it.)

In the states with conflicts, you will see, for example:

```
State 26

   21 anys: text . elts anys
   23     | text .

    NODE_START  shift, and go to state 1

    NODE_START  [reduce using rule 23 (anys)]

    head     go to state 4
    element  go to state 5
    comment  go to state 7
    cdata    go to state 8
    elt      go to state 27
    elts     go to state 35
```

The conflict is indicated by a lookahead (in this case `NODE_START`) with two or more different actions. The action(s) enclosed in brackets (in this case `[reduce using rule 23 (anys)]`) were eliminated by bison's conflict resolution mechanism (which, in the absence of precedence declarations, chooses the shift action if there is one, and otherwise the reduce action with the smallest production number).

The state dumps should make it clear why the rule `anys: text` became useless. In both cases where it could be reduced, there was a shift-reduce conflict and the shift action was preferred.

### 2. Cause of the shift-reduce conflict

The problem is `anys: text elts anys`. Consider an input consisting of three `elt`s. This could be parsed as an `elts` consisting of two `elt`s followed by an `elts` consisting of a single `elt`, or vice versa. The ambiguity causes a shift-reduce conflict.

Another problem with that production is that it does not permit an `elts` to end with a `text` (unless it consists only of a single `text`.

A better definition would be the simple

```
anys: any | anys any
```

Note: you are using a bottom-up parser and right recursion is (literally) an anti-pattern. Writing your lists left-recursively as above will limit parser stack usage and cause senantic actions to run in the expected order (that is, left to right). Unless you have very specific needs, you should avoid right recursion.